# Value not saved into the data class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, data-class, immutablelist

I am currently building an app and I have added Dagger Hilt in order to define a single class to access data. the injection seems working fine but I am not able to store a value in the data class I use.

I have created a Singleton first, which is used by the code to set/get value from a data structure.

```
@Singleton
class CarListMemorySource @Inject constructor() : CarListInterface {

    private var extendedCarList: ExtendedCarList? = null

    override fun setListOfVehicles(listOfVehicles: List<item>) 
    {
        extendedCarList?.listOfVehicles = listOfVehicles
    }

}
```

When I am calling `setListOfVehicles` the `listOfVehicules` contains 10 items but

The data structure `ExtendedCarList` is defined as below:

```
data class ExtendedCarList(
    var listOfVehicles: List<item>
)
```

The Singleton in passed using Hilt like for example in the viewModel below:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val carList: CarListMemorySource
): ViewModel() {

    fun getList() {
        --> DO SOMETHING TO Get A ListA
        carList.setListOfVehicles(ListA)
    }
}
```

And in the activity, using the viewModel, I am just doing this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeScreenActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

   private val viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel by viewModels()

....
    viewModel.getList()
....

}
```

Any idea why and how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: How r you using `CarListMemorySource`? if its singleton why not just use `object CarListMemorySource` .

Comment: @ADM I have added to remaining code

Answer (score 2):

you never initialize `extendedCarList`.

```
extendedCarList?.listOfVehicles = listOfVehicles
```

above line is exactly the same as

```
if (extendedCarList != null) extendedCarList.listOfVehicles = listOfVehicles
```

But it never passes the null check.

I think just changing

```
private var extendedCarList: ExtendedCarList? = null
```

to

```
private val extendedCarList = ExtendedCarList()
```

might solve it